# What is the rank of the matrix consisting of all permutations of one vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, matrix-rank

Let $a=(a_1,...,a_n)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a column vector and let $M_1,...,M_{n!}$ denote all $n\times n$ permutation matrices. When is the rank of the matrix that consists of all possible permutations of $a$:
$$ A=[M_1 a \,|\; ... \; |\, M_{n!} a]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n!} $$ 
equal to $n$?
Obviously, $rank(A)\le n$ and if all entries of $a$ are identical, then $rank(A)=1$. Moreover, if $A$ has rank $n$, then there exist two entries $i,j$ s.t. $a_i\not=a_j$. Is the converse statement also true?

Comment: I think you wanted to write *there not exist two entries*

Comment: The converse statement surely is not true: if you consider $a=(1,-1)$ then $rk(A)=1$

Comment: I think this is a [duplicate of this earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/75427/11619). As I answered that one I refrain from casting a duplicate vote. Also it is not clear which direction the closing should go given that Qiaochu's answer is very nice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the old question is more general as it considers arbitrary fields. Thus this one should be closed as dupe. I voted like this. (One might consider a merge. The modification to the answer needed seem minimal.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  Given the better wording of the other Question and the nice answer here by Qiaochu, this is perhaps a good candidate for merging?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The rank takes the following $4$ possible values in the following situations:

1. Rank $0$: $a = 0$.
2. Rank $1$: the $a_i$ are all equal to some nonzero scalar.
3. Rank $n-1$: the $a_i$ sum to $0$, and at least one is not zero.
4. Rank $n$: otherwise.

This is not hard to prove directly but can be fit into the general context of representation theory. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a representation of the symmetric group, and it decomposes as a direct sum of two irreducible representations, namely the trivial representation (spanned by the all-ones vector) and an irreducible representation of dimension $n-1$ (vectors summing to zero). If $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector, then

$$\text{span}(gv : g \in S_n)$$

is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and so must be a sum of irreducible subrepresentations. Moreover, in this case (although not in general) every such sum occurs. This gives the above.